# How to integrate Red into Rust?

Tags: user-interface, rust, red

Does anyone know how to use `view` from Rust? Do I need to link `libRed.dll` on Windows? What functions to extern? Must I try to disassemble it? I’m using compiled Red, not interpreted, so `libRedRT.lib` isn’t a solution, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Red contributor who started [such binding with Rust](https://twitter.com/red_lang/status/818367642989785089?s=20&t=g0-uJsQSRHctnEmW7N9orA) deleted his repo (or maybe moved it out of Github).

We have not yet tried interfacing Red with Rust in the core team, but it should not be difficult to achieve as Red is provided as a library you can link to C at run-time. All you need is to do is convert the [C import definitions](https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/libRed/red.h) for libRed to Rust format. Then you should be able to write a simple HelloWorld for it, translating the following C code to Rust:

```
#include "red.h"

int main() {
    redOpen();
    redPrint(redString("Hello World!"));
    redClose();
    return 0;
}
```

The whole libRed API is described [there](https://github.com/red/docs/blob/master/en/libred.adoc) and you can find some usage examples from C in the [tests](https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/tests/libRed/test.c).

EDIT: I have found [another Rust binding for libRed](https://github.com/hako/libred.rs).

Comment: I've already checked it, thanks, but couldn't find any information on does it require any additional runtime. While trying to link `libRed` to my binary using MSVC standard linker, I faced next problem: looks like functions that I'm trying to extern refer to other mysterious symbols (`__imp_redOpen` for `redOpen`, for example), and linker says "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_redClose referenced
in function {function where I used redClose}". Hope my text isn't a mishmash.

Comment: LibRed is only available as a shared library, not as a static library, so you cannot link it statically to your compiled binary using a linker, you can only load it at run-time.

Comment: Oh… well, I think I still can use `include_bytes` anyway. Thank you very much!